# Remap curved quotation marks in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

So, the default key combinations to manually insert curved quotation marks (“” and ‘’) in OS X are:

- `option + [` for “
- `option + ]` for ‘
- `option + shift + [` for ”
- `option + shift + ]` for ’

Possibly due to muscle memory and the mental association with the keys (`[` being an "opening" symbol and `]` being a "closing" one) I find this specific setup *very* confusing, so I'll always get it wrong when inserting curved quotation marks manually. And have to try all combinations until I get the right quote.

What I would like to achieve is the (IMO) more intuitive setup:

- `option + [` for “
- `option + ]` for ”
- `option + shift + [` for ‘
- `option + shift + ]` for ’

What setting/file/app I need to fiddle with to remap these characters? Is there a special keyboard layout I can download that will do this for me? Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm aware of the "smart quotes" feature, but I'd like to have more fine grained control, that's why I want the manual insertion to be intuitive for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**KeyRemap4MacBook**](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) with a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Manual Smart Quotes</name>
    <identifier>ManualSmartQuotes</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L
    </autogen>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, VK_OPTION, | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
      KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Does this work on non-MacBook keyboards?

Comment: @Peanut Yes, it works on any keyboard. The software was renamed Karabiner to avoid this kind of confusion, but the software has always had this functionality despite the name.